# <lightning input type="search"> reset to call a controller?

Tags: lightning, search, type

I using the search type input in a lightning component to do a dynamic search on a given field from a custom object. I've noticed when you click on the "X" to clear the data that came back from the search that there doesn't seem to be a way to recall the main controller so that the entire data set is retrieved again.

Here's the way I have the input type setup.

```
        <lightning:input type="search"
            aura:id="searchinput"
            label="{!v.fieldLabel}"
            name="{!v.fieldLabel}"
            value=""
            onchange="{!c.searchRecords}"
            isLoading="false"
            placeholder="{!v.placeholder}"
            onfocus="{!c.searchRecords}"
            onblur="{!c.searchRecords}"/>
```

The onchange is working correctly, but onblur (not idea to have to click off the list) doesn't seem to be working correctly. Has anyone else run into this?

Comment: I've created a simple event and have tested 2 cases: one calling component.find() off of the aura:id and getting the value and the other is using an aura:attribute and calling onchange on the input.  Both worked for me.  Any chances we could get the controller posted to see what logic you're calling?

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'd set a handler on the search term itself:

```
<aura:attribute name="searchTerm" 
                type="String" />
<aura:handler name="change" 
              value="{!v.searchTerm}" 
              action="{!c.searchRecords}" />
<lightning:input value="{!v.searchTerm}" 
                 type="search"
                 label="{!v.fieldLabel}"
                 name="{!v.fieldLabel}" 
                 placeholder="{!v.placeholder}" />
```

Comment: Thanks. I added that but clicking the "X" to clear the search field still doesn't reset the dataset.

Comment: @JoelGerber Wow. If that doesn't work, there's most definitely a bug. I haven't tried this myself, but I'll ask around.

Comment: Thanks. So my workaround was to change this to a text type. You lose the "X" to clear the search but when you delete the search characters the controller resets the dataset.